# Cross xml reference is not working

Tags: android

I created menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

but, in my activity xml the menu doesn't appear! 
So What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method in your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); // Specify your menu 'id' here
    return true;  
}
```